# Homebrew will not run wget command (Library not loaded)

Tags: macos, homebrew, wget, dyld

I received the following message when I try to use wget command after installation on Homebrew (running Mac High Sierra 10.13).

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/wget
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried to reinstall wget. Issue still persists.

Comment: The clue for these errors, which no-one's directly mentioned in their answers, is whichever library dyld is complaining about, look for the "Referenced from:" line which indicates which Homebrew formula you need to reinstall.

Answer (score 60):

`wget` gave me that error after migrating to a new macbook. What worked for me was

```
brew uninstall --force gettext
brew install gettext
```

Comment: Tried this on Mojave, did not fix the issue. If I come up with a solution I'll update here.

Comment: @Montag Dude. Dont give false hope

Comment: I never did find a solution, I found another way to solve my personal program problem. There was no false hope given, just honesty. I didn't find it so I didn't post it.

Comment: you caqn also do `brew reinstall wget`

Comment: I do not recommend this `uninstall --force` solution, because you can broke your dependencies

Answer (score 59):

```
brew uninstall wget
brew install wget
```

solved me both gettext and git clone issues.

Comment: Solved me `curl` issue as well.

Comment: The other answer about reinstalling gettext didn't work for me on Mojave either. This one worked.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix it by reinstall gettext

```
brew reinstall gettext
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I have tried a lot of methods, but the command `brew reinstall wget` solved my problems at last.

Answer (score 2):

A simple reinstall of "wget" fixed this issue in my case.

```
brew reinstall wget
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was installing the "libidn2" dependency

```
$ brew info wget
==> Dependencies
Required: libidn2 ✘, openssl@3 ✔
$ brew install libidn2
$ brew uninstall -f wget
$ brew info wget
==> Dependencies
Required: libidn2 ✔, openssl@3 ✔
```

Answer (score 1):

uninstall and reinstalling the brew will fix the issue

**Uninstall**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

**install**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Doing this after creating the Cellar and opt folder it needs inside /usr/local and assigning myself as the owner, helped. Thanks for the commands :)

Answer (score 1):

Likely problem with libintl.8.dylib as in many other similar issues:

```
brew link --overwrite ruby
brew uninstall --force gettext
brew install gettext

locate libintl.8.dylib
```

if /gettext//libintl.*.dylib exists

```
brew link -f gettext
```

go to (depending on version)

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew 
cd /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
```

and execute (make sure you're in .../Homebrew directory)

```
git pull origin master
rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
brew update && brew upgrade
```

this last will took some time, but afterwards everything should work fine.

Comment: Holy smoke, this answer from 4 years ago solved my problems. I suspect it was because I had ruby, angular, and various other things installed. In any case, the locate command took a while to work after the install. I also had to go to: /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew to do the git pull, etc. Kudos for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the following error:

```
Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libunistring/lib/libunistring.2.dylib
```

Before attempting `brew uninstall --force gettext` try the following:

```
brew install libidn2
```

Answer (score 0):

`brew update` and `brew upgrade` resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue with git , fixed it with brew reinstall gettext

Comment: Hi there! It seems this solution has already been proposed. On this site, posting duplicate answers is discouraged.